# What's the difference between atomic.store and atomic_thread_fence?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model

I've been asked about the differences between these two functions of f and g:

```
atomic<int> var(1);
int a = 1;

void f() {
 a=123;
 var.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
}

void g() {
 a=123;
 std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
 var.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

In my opinion they have same effects, because if other threads read `var=0` we can be sure that `a=123`, right?

Comment: The example is too simplistic. Stores and loads affect only one memory location, a fence affects all memory locations. Synchronizing on a load/store pair is in some sense the more economical and more deliberate way to synchronize.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, and I think in this simple case they should have same effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions `f()` and `g()` are a correct implementation of release logic and behave the same.

Whether other threads read `a==123` if `var==0` depends on whether the data was acquired:

```
if (var.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0)
{
    assert(a==123);
}
```

Or:

```
if (var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0)
{
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    assert(a==123);
}
```

Both asserts cannot fire